# Adding array elements through multiple form fields in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, forms, react-state-management

I am working on a quiz app project to learn to react. I came across a situation where I need to store incorrect options in a quiz question in an array. And later pass over the information to the database.
This is an example JSON format.

```
{       
        incorrect_answers:["Jeff Bezos","Satya Nadela","Bill Gates"] }
```

The incorrect answer is an array and the value needs to be inputted through separate text boxes for each incorrect option like this.
[option input form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDCc3.png)

The part where I am stuck is appending them to the array here is my attempt.

```
export default class CreateQuiz extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
   
          this.onChangedIncorrectAnswer=this.onChangedIncorrectAnswer.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit=this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state={
        incorrect_answers:[]
    } 
    
    
}

onChangedIncorrectAnswer(e){
    const option=e.target.value
    this.setState({
        incorrect_answers:[...this.state.incorrect_answers,option]
    });
}


onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    const quiz = {
        incorrect_answers:this.state.incorrect_answers
    }

    console.log(quiz);
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/quizes",quiz)
    .then(res=>console.log(res.data));
    window.location='/quiz-list';
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Create New Quiz</h3>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
           
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Incorrect Option 1</label>
                    <input type="text"
                        required
                        className="form-control"
                        value={this.state.incorrect_answers[0]}
                        onChange={this.onChangedIncorrectAnswer}
                        />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Incorrect Option 2</label>
                    <input type="text"
                        required
                        className="form-control"
                        value={this.state.incorrect_answers[1]}
                        onChange={this.onChangedIncorrectAnswer}
                        />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Incorrect Option 3</label>
                    <input type="text"
                        required
                        className="form-control"
                        value={this.state.incorrect_answers[2]}
                        onChange={this.onChangedIncorrectAnswer}
                        />
                </div>

            
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" className="btn btn-primary"/>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

But the form was not working as expected. When I enter content for the first option in the "Option 1" text box only the first character is stored remaining in "Option 2" and so on.

Comment: Remember to simplify your example down as much as possible. Are there any parts of your example that we don't need to see?  You also need to explain what actually happens. Is anything getting added to the array? Is the form not submitting correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, this would work!!

```
export default class CreateQuiz extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.onChangedCorrectAnswer = this.onChangedCorrectAnswer.bind(this);
this.onChangedIncorrectAnswer = this.onChangedIncorrectAnswer.bind(this);
this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

this.state = {
  category: "",
  correct_answer: "",
  difficulty: "",
  type: "",
  question: "",
  incorrect_answers: ["", "", ""]
  };
}

 onChangedCorrectAnswer(e) {
   this.setState({
  correct_answer: e.target.value
  });
 }

 onChangedIncorrectAnswer(e, index) {
  const option = e.target.value;
  const { incorrect_answers } = this.state;
  incorrect_answers[index] = option;
 this.setState({
  incorrect_answers
 });
}

onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

const quiz = {
  category: this.state.category,
  correct_answer: this.state.correct_answer,
  incorrect_answers: this.state.incorrect_answers,
  difficulty: this.state.difficulty,
  type: this.state.type,
  question: this.state.question
};

console.log(quiz);
axios
  .post("http://localhost:3000/quizes", quiz)
  .then((res) => console.log(res.data));
window.location = "/quiz-list";
}

render() {
  return (
  <div>
    <h3>Create New Quiz</h3>
    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Correct Answer</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          required
          className="form-control"
          value={this.state.correct_answer}
          onChange={this.onChangedCorrectAnswer}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Incorrect Option 1</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          required
          className="form-control"
          value={this.state.incorrect_answers[0]}
          onChange={(e) => this.onChangedIncorrectAnswer(e, 0)}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Incorrect Option 2</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          required
          className="form-control"
          value={this.state.incorrect_answers[1]}
          onChange={(e) => this.onChangedIncorrectAnswer(e, 1)}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Incorrect Option 3</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          required
          className="form-control"
          value={this.state.incorrect_answers[2]}
          onChange={(e) => this.onChangedIncorrectAnswer(e, 2)}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Submit Quiz"
          className="btn btn-primary"
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Your array state is considered as one state only
Why don't you create state on the go when user do any change in the input.

create a state object like

```
this.state = {incorrect_answers: {}}
```

In your onChangedIncorrectAnswer

```
onChangedIncorrectAnswer(e){
    const option=e.target.value;
    const stateName = e.target.name;
    this.setState({
        incorrect_answers: {...this.state.incorrect_answers, [stateName]: option }
    });
}
```

use your form element as add name as unique which will be used as state

```
<div className="form-group">
    <label>Incorrect Option 1</label>
    <input name="incorrect_answers_0" type="text" required className="form-control" value={this.state.incorrect_answers[incorrect_answers_0]}
        onChange={this.onChangedIncorrectAnswer} />
</div>
```

use that object while saving

```
onSubmit(e){
    let yourIncorrectAnswers = Object.values(this.state.incorrect_answers);
  })
    

}
```